# EXT.Net - Dynamic UserControlLoader with Property

Tags: ext.net

I need a solution to the below scenario. I'm developing an application in ASP.Net with the help of EXT.Net Controls.

In my scenario, I'm creating dynamic tabs (EXT.Net) and loading an User Control dynamically with UserControlLoader component.

How can I pass a parameter to the UserControl dynamically? Below is my sample code.

```
[DirectMethod]
public void AddNewTab()
{
    getTitle gt = new getTitle();
    Ext.Net.Panel panel = new Ext.Net.Panel
    {
        Title = gt.Title(),
        Closable = false,
        Layout = "Fit",
        Items = {
                    new UserControlLoader{
                    Path="ElementChooser.ascx"
                    }
                }
    };
    TabPanel1.Add(panel);
    panel.Render();
    TabPanel1.SetLastTabAsActive();
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear what "pass a parameter to a User Control" means, but I think you need to handle the UserControlLoader's OnUserControlAdded and OnComponentAdded events.

The first one fires when a user control is added to a UserControlLoader.

The second one fires for each top level Ext.NET component from a user control.

These events helps to configure a user control and its components as needed.

Here is an [example](http://examples.ext.net/#/Combination_Samples/Applications/Feed_Viewer/) with the OnComponentAdded example.

Comment: I have two public properties in a UserControl. I need to pass values to that properties from parent page dynamically. That's what I meant.

Comment: Ok, the OnUserControlAdded event appears what you need. Here is [an example](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?21553#post105138).